# How can I synchronise TortoiseGit with an existing repository?

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I have a repository in github, that I have cloned to my local computer(using command line).

I want to use [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/).

How can I synchronize this repository with TortoiseGit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseGit is just another Git client, so once you have cloned the repo onto your machine, there is nothing you need to do to "sync" it with TortoiseGit. Once TortoiseGit is installed, you can right click on a file/folder in the repo and you will see all the options.

Comment: Thanks, you are right but why do not I see the icon on the folders and files?